# Create match queue from list of javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have list of jobs that needs to be perform based on the data and device.
This is my sample data

```
device = [ device0, device1, device2 ]
device0 = {
    group: [MATCH1, MATCH2]
}
device1 = {
    group: [MATCH1, MATCH2, MATCH3]
}
device2 = {
    group: [MATCH2, MATCH3]
}
data = {
  "destination": "destination",
  "text": "Test send message",
  "hlr": "MATCH2"
}
```

How can i fix my code so that my data can match and perform task to device. I'm sorry this is my first question. I'm still learning programming and I'm not fluent in english.
This is my sample code :

```
const jobs = []
jobs.push(data)
        if (jobs.length > 0) {
            let task= jobs.shift()
            device.push(device.splice(0, 1)[0]); // swap device position
            dataLoop: for (var i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
                itemLoop: for (var j = 0; j < device[0].group.length; j++) { // cycle through until find match
                    if (device[0].group[j].toString() === data.hlr.toString()) {
                        console.log(device[0].group[j] + ':' + data.hlr.toString()); // output should be MATCH2 : MATCH2
                        break dataLoop;
                    }
                }
                device.push(device.splice(0, 1)[0]);
            }
            device[0].sendData({ // using first device to perform task
                receiver: data.destination,
                text: data.text,
                request_status: true
            }, function(err, ref) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                   if (err) { console.log(err) }
                   console.log(ref)
                }, 5000)
            });
        }
```

Comment: I just need to match data.hlr with list of device[group] and something like 
if data.hlr === device1.group[2] then using those device to sendData. I'm sorry,it has been fixed for group property. 
device.push(device.splice(0, 1)[0]) // Actually I'm using this code to reverse the first and last position devices array before loop to  ensure next data processed by different device. Thanks

Comment: yep ive got that now, but theres then a typo in your second for loop. Must be device[0] not device[i]

Comment: I'm sorry. It has been fixed now. Thank you very much :D

Comment: i will add it as an answer to close this thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a typo:

```
itemLoop: for (var j = 0; j < device[i].group.length; j++) {
```

must be

```
itemLoop: for (var j = 0; j < device[0].group.length; j++) { //
```